# How to create an animation of a waterflow, from a sequence of .stl files

Tags: rendering, animation, video

I am trying to make a video for a waterflow surface around a fixed box. From my CFD (Computational Fluid Dynamics) software I export the water surface as a sequence of .stl files, one per frame, so thousands of .stl files total.

In Blender, I want to render a video of that flow; So, how should I do that ?

All I can see is import a stl file, render the frame, save it, and do the same for the next stl file, and this for every stl files; but I have thousands of stl files...

EDIT:
I understand that there is no easy way to do this, but I have read that one way to do it is to use a python script to either toggle the surface visibility after I imported them all, or either process one surface face after another.
I have never used any script of this type before and I am new to blender, is there a similar script I could download and tweak to my case ? Or some kind of tutorial for that specific case ? I assume I am not the first one willing to do this type of video.

Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think there is really a satisfactory way to do this at the moment, without slow python scripts.. IIRC there was some mention about making the mesh cache modifier support mesh sequences, but I don't think that will be here for a little while yet.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I was hoping there would be a simple solution to that.

Comment: The linked answer mentions an addon which you might have a look at: http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?252844-Script-Meshfoot-OBJ-Sequence-Manager-%28revised-for-Blender-2-66%29

Comment: You might try the Blender add-on Stop Motion OBJ.  It supports sequences of .PLY, .OBJ, and .STL files. It also supports geometry with different vertex counts from frame to frame.https://github.com/neverhood311/Stop-motion-OBJ